# Why do we send a ref to ostream obj to ostream overloadings?

Tags: c++, ostream

I didn't get the intuition behind this way of writing implementation when we want to create a class-specific ostream object.

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Object& obj);
```

It has such a use. It is passed one parameter while using with operator overloading. But during the definition, we've written *ostream& out* as being the first parameter. How is it passed the first parameter under the hood? Is it an implicit way of sending parameters that I am not aware of? Lastly, where is *out* object, which is referenced to, stored? Is it a global variable that is automatically called by overloaded functions as such?

```
cout << obj
```

Comment: You have a number of basic misconceptions here, so I think the best thing to do is to refer you to your textbook's complete explanation of operator overloading and how it works. What does your textbook say on this topic, and is there anything in your textbook's explanation that's unclear to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Object& obj);
```

is a binary operator (like `+`, `-`, ...). It takes 2 operands and returns something.

In this case it's

```
auto result = operand1 << operand2;
```

with `result` being `operand1` (the original `ostream`)

just like

```
int operator+(int operand1, int operand2);
int result = operand1 + operand2;
```

And btw. you're not creating a

> class-specific ostream object

you're just defining the streaming operator for your user defined type, to work with ostreams. So you're defining what should happen when you write expressions like `some_ostream << myObject;`
The `std::ostream` doesn't magically know how to handle your class, so you have to define that operator for your type in order to use it.

### Edit:

as "S.M." pointed out in a comment, the reason this operator should return the original `std::ostream&` (the left operand) is, that you can chain calls to this operator:

```
std::cout << myObj1 << " foo " << myObj2 << " bar ";
```

which can be read as:

```
(((std::cout << myObj1) << " foo ") << myObj2) << " bar ";
```

and is equivalent to:

```
std::cout << myObj1;
std::cout << " foo ";
std::cout << myObj2;
std::cout << " bar ";
```

And it should really be

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Object& obj); // const
```

because 1. you should not manipulate that object and 2. you want to be able to use it with `const` objects

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've surmised that the first parameter is the one of which we access the method rather than a parameter which is used by Compiler to detect to proper implementation we look for.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz Yes, it's not a method of `std::ostream`, it's a free function.

Comment: One important thing is missing. Returned stream allows to use the stream sequentially like `cout << obj1 << obj2 << std::endl;`